# SQL Server : create a column by summing another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new column in my table by summing up values from another column within the same table

Here is an example:

```
Header 1     Header 2      Header 3       (new column)
------------------------------------------------------
1            1             1               1
2            2             6              12
3            2             6              12
4            3             4               8
5            3             4               8
```

I want the sum to be done categorically based on the categories in Header 2, with the values of Header 3.

What SQL code can I use for this?

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that produces the wrong output?

Comment: Look into using SUM OVER() PARTION BY [Header 2]

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need window function :

```
select t.*, sum(header3) over (partition by header2) as newcol
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cte structure like:

```
;with cte (header2,Total) as (
  select header2,sum(header3) as Total
  from table 
  group by header2
)
select t.*,cte.Total
from table t
inner join cte on cte.header2 = t.header2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
SELECT T1.*,
       (SELECT SUM(Header3) FROM T WHERE Header2 = T1.Header2) ExpectedResults
FROM T T1;
```